# How to send email asynchronously but as soon as possible?

Tags: email, language-agnostic, asynchronous

I've just read this [excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2617153/759866) about the advantages of sending an email asynchronously vs synchronously.

I fully agree with the approach that the single answer concludes, which is: store the email to send in a queue, and return the page to the user as soon as possible.

My current implementation uses a database table to store the email queue. This approach has several advantages:

- It's very fast: saving a record to a table takes no time, as opposed to placing an API call (emails are sent through Amazon SES).
- It's transactional: if anything goes wrong, the transaction is rolled back, and my email will never be sent for an account that wouldn't have been committed to the database.

Then I've implemented a job that runs permanently, and will check on a regular basis (currently 30s) if there are some mails to send, and process them.

I'm happy enough with this solution, apart from the fact that it's not exactly instant. People often expect to receive a mail (even more if it's a SMS) in the next few seconds.

I could obviously make the job pause no more than one second between two runs, but I don't want to waste server resources needlessly with frequent transactions. Also, because my emails are sent through an API call, I'd benefit from concurrent processing, which my current implementation does not do (it processes them sequentially).

Are there some common solutions to still process the email asynchronously, but start processing as soon as the email has been sent to the queue?

Answer (score 0):

When you put an e-mail into the database, you also send a notification to your e-mail sending job to wake it up and send the new e-mail.  Rather than waiting for the sending job to check, it is actively notified and deals with the new e-mail immediately.

Comment: They're on different machines though, is there some kind of standardized notification system for this?

Comment: Pass.  That very much depends on what you have running on the two machines.  In principle, it should be possible to pass messages between the machines.  The details may get somewhat complex though, depending.